# Excel formula or database lookup for mapping multi-valued cell to multi-valued result?

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets in Excel.

One is a mapping, for example

```
A Aardvark
B Bear
C Cow
D Dog
```

The other is a table whose 2nd column I want to complete automatically. The first column contains single values, or multiple values comma-separated:

```
A
A, C
D, B
C
```

The result I want in the 2nd column is

```
Aardvark
Aardvark, Cow
Dog, Bear
Cow
```

As long as 1st column cells contain only single values, it's easy with Excel VLOOKUP.

But it doesn't handle multiple values (or rather, it misunderstands them as single values) and gives result

```
Aardvark
#NA
#NA
Cow
```

How can I get the desired result? Perhaps with more complex formula, different Excel function, array tables, or using MS-SQL client in Excel to query the Excel tables as a database?

Comment: splitting column with "Data", "Text To Columns..." first?

Comment: @Luca yes thanks that's what I am doing meanwhile as a workaround, depending on the constraint that my real dataset apparently meets: that there are maximum 3 values. Splitting data, will use multiple vlookups, then concatenate results. But hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Actually what is more repeatable, with the max 3 values constraint, is to write formulas using LEFT, MID, and RIGHT to separate the text. That way I can ensure that the VLOOKUP works properly. Still a workaround though.

Comment: You could use a UDF which runs Split() on the value, then loops though the array doing a vlookup on each element. Concatenate and return the result.

Comment: @Tim Williams - Aha! User-defined function (UDF). That sounds like a direction. Post as an answer instead of a comment and I will likely mark it as the accepted answer when I'm next online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDF approach:

```
Function MultiVL(v As Range, tbl As Range)

    Dim arr, rv As String, x As Integer, res

    rv = ""
    arr = Split(v.Value, ",")
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        res = Application.VLookup(Trim(arr(x)), tbl, 2, False)
        rv = rv & IIf(rv <> "", ", ", "") & IIf(IsError(res), "?", res)
    Next x

    MultiVL = rv

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. It works great after I realized how to call it. I had been confused by the "As Range" on the input parameter 'v' -- incorrectly called function with my entire input range because it said "As Range". Then I realized that even one cell is a Range. When I call it correctly as =MultiVL(A2,Mapping) where A2 is an input _cell_ and Mapping is the mapping _range_, works great. Goes to show the value of comments or a usage example. But I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Also shows the importance of remembering what _functional_ programming is. Even though that's why I like Excel, the minute I was looking at a procedural program (the VBA code) I forgot that from the Excel formula point of view it is a function. (Forgot even though the VBA is clearly labeled "Function ... End Function".) Since the function is supposed to look up a single cell's (multiple sub-string) values, I should have remembered that way too that the first parameter was a single cell.

Comment: BTW I must also commend you for supplying a function that includes error-handling. Very thorough!